Is the RAM that NICs (Network Interface Cards) have onboard sectioned into different areas similar to system memory/RAM?
Is the RAM that NICs have onboard sectioned into different areas similar to system memory/RAM? Like is it sectioned into buffers for receiving and sending network packets, the next section for DMA descriptors (memory addresses on where in the system memory shall it be stored), etc…?
For example in system memory you can sections or areas where it belongs to the kernel and all the kernel's data and code runs there, and then you have the user space which normally is the rest of the memory addresses.
And an additional question is that normally when receiving network packets and storing them in these locations inside the NIC's onboard memory, does the memory address grow downwards or upwards?

"For example in system memory you can sections or areas where it belongs to the kernel ... , and then you have the user space ..." - You seem to be referring to the memory partitioning used by different processor modes. A NIC would not bother to use more than one processor mode.

"normally when receiving network packets and storing them ..." - The typical NIC uses a ring list of buffers. There's one ring list for transmission, and another for reception. Each buffer is sized to hold one standard Ethernet frame. Buffers can be chained for a long Ethernet packet. The buffers are typically allocated in the host system's main memory, although a high-end NIC adapter could have its own on-board memory for frames.

The SMSC LAN911x Ethernet chips are an example that have have TX and RX FIFOs instead of using buffer ring or lists in main memory.

There's no standard. It's an implementation detail. Anyone designing a NIC can segment or not segment their RAM however they want.

oh alright, but the other question was that when network packets (just gonna call it data) arrives, when the data is stored on the onboard memory, will it grow downwards into lower memory address regions or upwards into higher regions?

@19216811 - How the onboard memory addressing works likely depends on the specific network adapter. Perhaps if we understood what problem you were trying to solve we could answer that instead of answering a question that likely doesn't have a single answer.

yeah sorry my question is a bit of a generalization that's why

@19216811 - Generalized questions don't do well; it would benefit the entire community if you focused on the question.

https://github.com/ucsdsysnet/corundum is an Open source FPGA-based NIC and platform for in-network compute. Corundum has several unique architectural features. First, transmit, receive, completion, and event queue states are stored efficiently in block RAM or ultra RAM, enabling support for thousands of individually-controllable queues. These queues are associated with interfaces, and each interface can have multiple ports, each with its own independent scheduler. This enables extremely fine-grained control over packet transmission.
